Mysqldump - different lengths of extended insert
I have two copies of the same database on two different servers with the same version of MariaDB. When I run mysqldump (with default params) on those, I get two very similar dump files but for some tables it separates the extended inserts differently (one row back and forth).
I found out it depends on net_buffer_length variable, but there's the same value on both servers (16384). I want to compare those two dump files as a test of my integrations, so I'm expecting the diff to be empty, so I'm getting false positive results. Did anyone face (or better solve) the same problem?

Forgot to mention that both files have exactly the same size.

you can start the dump with the parameter --print-defaults , to see if the is any init file with some different options. here is the manual page from MariaDB : https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-dump/ . you also can test to dump the databases from the same server, to use only one dump

Thank you. The --print-defaults parameter prints nothing.
What I'm trying to do is I have dev and production server and I want to test if my integration has the same result on both. So I create "before" and "after" dumps on production, move those to dev, restore the "before" dump on dev, run the integration on newer version of the source codes, dump the database and run diff against the "after" dump expecting empty result.

If you are getting the data in the same order, but with slightly different numbers of rows per line, try using the same mysqldump binary, connecting to both hosts (or load the after dump from production in dev and redump it there, so your dev after and production after are both generated in dev).  If that doesn't help, you likely will need to use --skip-extended-insert (and if you actually intend to load from these dumps, do a separate dump with extended inserts, using the skip extended insert dump only for doing your comparison).
Your goal may still be problematic, given that data rows have no intrinsic order.  You should use the --order-by-primary parameter, but if you have tables with no primary or unique key, that won't help.  You could dump one table at a time and sort the dump files before comparison in that case.
